# What are the most important reasons that large urban centers in the U.S. tend to lean towards democrats?

Tags: united-states, republican-party, democratic-party

There are many candidate explanations for this: the relatively less important role of religion, the relatively higher level of education, the fact that living in crowded areas leads people to appreciate interdependence, etc.

However, I am looking for more serious scientific studies that seriously test these explanations, instead of just telling stories. If you know any sources, please let me know.

Comment: Ethnicity will come into it at some level. Urban centers tend to be considerably less white than the suburban and rural areas that encircle them.

Comment: @Crazymoomin Urban whites are much more liberal the rural whites.

Comment: @ohwilleke It's not necessarily a conservative/liberal thing, ethnic minorities are more likely to vote democrat regardless of their actual political views. The litmus test would be to find an overwhelmingly white urban center for comparison.

Comment: @Crazymoomin Ethnic minorities (e.g. Muslims) who are Democrats are often more conservative than white Democrats, but all Democrats are much more liberal than Republicans. This wasn't always the case but the parties are now firmly divided into liberal and conservative camps to a purity not seen at any time in recent history.

Comment: @ohwilleke Considering how much party loyalty is valued in the GOP, I'd personally hesitate to make such a statement. On issues like LGBT rights some Muslims can be _very_ conservative, more than most moderate republicans.

Comment: @Crazymoomin American Muslims are certainly among the most conservative Democratic leaning demographics in the U.S., but end up in the Democratic party among other things, because conservatives (on average) really, really hate them, and Democrats think they should be equal participants in society with right. Also, due to involvement in the Democratic Party, Muslims in the U.S. (who are also much more affluent than Muslims globally) are among the most liberal Muslims in the world. Of course wrt to the question, the Muslim numbers are too small to make a difference.

Comment: @Crazymoomin The fact that the GOP focuses on party loyalty doesn't mean that liberals aren't as well.  In fact both sides have become more divided lately and more likely to stick to 'party loyalty', likely due to technologically supported echo chambers ensuring they only hear that their 'side' is right and the other side wrong.  The idea of 'conservative democrat', or 'liberal republican' is becoming less and less relevant due to this increase in party loyalty.  Studies show people will side with their party views just because it's *their* parties views.

Comment: @dsollen O.K., I eventually decided to address the points raised in your comment and some others with a much extended narrative.

Comment: @ohwilleke You just made my point there. Muslims, Hispanics and even some African-Americans vote Democrat because they think the Republicans don't like them, _regardless_ of their political views on economics, LGBT issues, inequality and many more. Yes, American Muslims may be fairly liberal compared to Wahabists in Saudi Arabia, but you'd probably find more tolerance of gay marriage in the center-right libertarians than many of them. Despite a two party system, politics is still complicated.

Comment: @dsollen I disagree. Democrats seem to be prone to more infighting and factionalism than Republicans, even when their leadership is at stake. I don't think this is necessarily bad, blind loyalty with no dissent makes it difficult to change or compromise, but on the other hand it can weaken a party's ability to win elections. Regardless, I think it's important to emphasise the difference between party politics and personal politics. Moderates can exist but support a more extreme party _if they have no other parties they find acceptable_. And in the US, that's certainly the case for many people.

Comment: Large urban centers have high concentrations of people receiving some kind of government handout.  Wellfare, WIC, etc, etc,.  Those programs tend to be pushed harder by the democrat party. Urban centers also instill the idea of take from one and give to another for whatever public projects there might be.  These are also "big government" programs, primarily of democratic origin.  Suburban & rural areas are more self-sufficient, even the poor, and are thus opposed to the government taking their money for uses they don't directly control or benefit from.

Comment: @mikem The highest concentrations of people receiving government handouts are in places like rural Kentucky.

Comment: But in a given concentration of people, such as urban centers, there are a huge number of people receiving government handouts per/population/sq.mile.  This concentration within a specific urban center has a huge impact on how the politics of urban centers plays-out and why almost all of them lean left/democrat.  Comparing 20sq.mi of urban space with 100's of sq.miles of rural kentucky isn't quite the same.  We all know vast rural areas have lots of poor people, but they don't have the same collective "lean" or voting impact that poor people in urban centers do.

Answer (score 6):

> There are many candidate explanations for this: the relatively less
> important role of religion, the relatively higher level of education,
> the fact that living in crowded areas leads people to appreciate
> interdependence, etc. . . . **I am looking for more serious scientific
> studies that seriously test these explanations, instead of just
> telling stories.**

The question is basically looking for a [structural functionalist explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_functionalism) of partisan leanings associated with population density. And, this kind of explanation can explain some of what we see. But the political ideologies of people don't have only these kinds of structural functionalist roots.

The full story can only fully be described in a path dependent narrative in which history and inertia overcome the general considerations that apply *ceteris paribus* (all other things being equal). Particularly when it comes to explaining why urban ethnic and religious minorities tend to be Democratic party leaning even when their economic circumstances would suggest otherwise, it is necessary to tell stories (which is what history does), and these explanations are not less serious simply because they are historical narratives which need to be understood rather than reductive formulas and general principles.

**Population Density and Partisan Lean Are Strongly But Not Perfectly Related**

The place to begin is to recognize that this correlation is real and well established. Population density is a [first order strongly correlated predictor of partisan preference](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/how-urban-or-rural-is-your-state-and-what-does-that-mean-for-the-2020-election/), all other things being equal. It isn't a perfect correlation, however. A scatter plot of states by population density v. partisan lean in the 2016 election illustrates the point:

[image]

This doesn't just hold true in Presidential elections:

> The median Republican Congressional district now has a population
> density 11 times smaller than the median Democratic district[.]

[image]

From [here](https://www.blogger.com/blog/post/edit/14162253/7861072013593435073#). Chart from [here](https://www.thetransportpolitic.com/2011/01/25/understanding-the-republican-partys-reluctance-to-invest-in-transit-infrastructure/), which goes on to explain:

> As shown in the chart above (in Log scale), there was a relatively
> strong positive correlation between density of congressional districts
> and the vote share of the Democratic candidate in the 2010 elections.
> Of densest quartile of districts with a race between a Democrat and a
> Republican — 105 of them, with a density of 1,935 people per square
> miles or more — the Democratic candidate won 89. Of the quartile of
> districts with the lowest densities — 98 people per square mile and
> below — Democratic candidates only won 23 races.

**Economic productivity and population density are related**

To a significant extent, the relationship between population density and partisan lean echos another [well established economic relationship](https://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/abs/10.1162/REST_a_00065?journalCode=rest), which is that "productivity increases by 7% to 15% when the municipality population density doubles" that has been replicated across many cultures, economy types and time periods. [Others studies](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2012-12-10/why-denser-cities-are-smarter-and-more-productive#:%7E:text=Specifically%2C%20doubling%20density%20increases%20productivity,of%20two%20to%20four%20percent.) suggest the same relationship but suggests a slightly weaker but still consistent relationship: "doubling density increases productivity by an average of two to four percent." See also, e.g., [here](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Erehall/Productivity-AER-March-1996.pdf).

[image]

Image from [here](https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/urbanization-vs-gdp).

[image]

> 52% of total GDP [is] created in America’s 20 top metropolitan areas.

The quotation and image is from [here](https://www.visualcapitalist.com/this-stunning-3d-map-shows-u-s-economic-contribution-by-city/).

**Economic Prosperity and Partisan Leanings Are Related**

Well done multi-cultural evaluations of world values, such as the [World Values Survey](http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/WVSContents.jsp?CMSID=findings) show that, in general, liberal and secular leaning political views thrive in circumstances that are more economically prosperous and secure, while conservative and religious political views thrive in circumstances of economic scarcity and insecurity. As David Brooks [explains](https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/politics/david-brooks-the-rotting-of-the-republican-mind/ar-BB1brv2z) this works in the context of domestic politics as well:

> People need a secure order to feel safe. Deprived of that, people
> legitimately feel cynicism and distrust, alienation and anomie. This
> precarity has created, in nation after nation, intense populist
> backlashes against the highly educated folks who have migrated to the
> cities and accrued significant economic, cultural and political power.
> Will Wilkinson of the Niskanen Center calls this the “[Density Divide](https://www.niskanencenter.org/the-density-divide-urbanization-polarization-and-populist-backlash/)."

Wilkinson's analysis at the link above explains that:

> [U]rbanization is a relentless, glacial social force that transforms
> entire societies and, in the process, generates cultural and political
> polarization by segregating populations along the lines of the traits
> that make individuals more or less responsive to the incentives that
> draw people to the city. I explore three such traits — ethnicity,
> ideology-correlated aspects of personality, and level of educational
> achievement — and their intricate web of relationships. The upshot is
> that, over the course of millions of moves over many decades, high
> density areas have become economically thriving multicultural havens
> while whiter, lower density places are facing stagnation and decline
> as their populations have become increasingly uniform in terms of
> socially conservative personality, aversion to diversity, and lower
> levels of education. This self-segregation of the population, I argue,
> created the polarized economic and cultural conditions that led to
> populist backlash.

Certainly, one important factor mediating the connection between partisan leaning and population density is economic prosperity and productivity, even though it isn't a perfect predictor.

In the U.S., blue counties average about double the per capita GDP of red counties. For example, even though Biden won about 53% of the popular vote in 2020, counties he won had about [70% of the U.S. GDP](https://www.brookings.edu/blog/the-avenue/2020/11/09/biden-voting-counties-equal-70-of-americas-economy-what-does-this-mean-for-the-nations-political-economic-divide/) while counties that Trump won had about 30% of U.S. GDP (a GDP per capita ratio of 2.07).

**Migration and Diversity**

Migration is the primary mechanism by which economic prosperity which established regional norms and ideological world views and political understandings transmits itself to less economically prosperous people in the same area who move there to participate in the prosperity that they have not yet themselves attained. Migrants adopt local worldviews and ideologies because the whole point of them moving to these prosperous areas was to integrate themselves into the local cultural in order to ultimately share in that prosperity.

It is a similar phenomena to poor conservatives supporting abolishing estate taxes that they will never pay because they see themselves as part of that dream that they might someday face that problem, even if that is not a realistic assumption.

It is certainly true that urban areas are more racially and ethnically diverse than rural areas, on average, in the U.S., although it is a bit more complicated than that, because the reasons that areas outside the South are diverse are primarily due to voluntary acts, while the racial diversity of the South is primary rooted in the inherently involuntary institution of slavery which prevailed until 1865 there, and had *de facto* vestiges that continues much longer and still remain to this day in some respects.

> [In the U.S. House of Representatives] Districts represented by
> Democrats are, together, only slightly more than half white and nearly
> one quarter Hispanic. Republican districts are roughly three-quarters
> white, and only one in nine residents is Hispanic.

From [here](https://www.blogger.com/blog/post/edit/14162253/7958197123203469537#).

The case of the American South and its impact on the larger political system and process of ideology formation in ethnic and religious minorities in the U.S. is something of a case of American exceptionalism driven by its history of slavery and racism. Basically, the more conservative party (the Democrats in the post-Civil War era and the Republicans in the post-Civil Rights movement era) interposed itself to demonize ethnic minorities as a way to bolster poor whites.

Outside the South, the ethnic diversity of urban areas is largely a function of migration driven by urban prosperity.

Immigrants to the U.S. from abroad disproportionately migrated to these region in the hopes that they should share in the economic prosperity of those regions, particularly as urban areas gained more of an economic edge relative to rural areas over time.

Outside the South, the lion's share of African-Americans migrated within the U.S. to regions outside the South for similar reasons, especially during the "[Great Migration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Migration_%28African_American%29)" from around 1910 to 1970 in the United States, when African Americans migrated in large numbers to industrial cities in the North for manufacturing jobs. Prior to that, African Americans were overwhelmingly residents of the American South (i.e. the former Confederate States).

These groups and a lot of other minority ethnicities, however, defied the usual trend of affiliating with the more conservative party and developing those ideologies despite economically struggling once they arrived.

In contrast, ethnic and religious minorities have avoided rural America which has been in more or less continuous economic decline (collectively, outside newly settled frontiers where there was growth because there was no agriculture or modern economic activity of note there in the eyes of the settlers) since the 1790s, since economic opportunity for newcomers has been lacking there and since they weren't welcome and that lack of welcome wasn't worth overcoming in the face of stagnant economic prospects for newcomers.

The American South, however, is another story, that spilled out to influence political ideology at a mass grass roots level nationwide among ethnic and religious minorities in the U.S. There, the longstanding legacy of slavery and its recent dismantlement (compared, for example, to the demise of serfdom in Europe) helps explain why the usual considerations have been overcome there and spilled out to other parts of the U.S.

African American alienation from the modern Republican political party can be traced, fairly clearly, to the outright racism and hostility present in the Republican party which became the new home of segregationist Southerners (the former "Dixiecrats") who wanted to keep first de jure and then de facto and private sector discrimination against African Americans in place.  Republicans have, at every step, opposed the integration of public institutions, viable employment discrimination laws, and viable remedies for victims of abuse in the criminal justice system (particularly those like the sentencing disparities between powder and crack cocaine that disproportionately impact African Americans for no principled reason).  Republicans have opposed African American judicial and cabinet nominees (with the notable exception of African American conservative U.S. Supreme Court Justice Thomas).  Republicans have favored regressive taxation schemes and weak social welfare safety nets in ways that have done disproportionate economic harm to African Americans.  Republicans have opposed history instruction in schools that highlights African American contributions.  Republicans opposed making Martin Luther King, Jr. day a holiday.

Republicans have also not historically been very welcoming other conservative leaning immigrant groups like Muslims and Protestant Hispanics.

The Democratic party, in contrast (during the time period that it was the more liberal party), has had the back of African Americans on issues with strong racial overtones for the last half century or more, has consistently advanced African American economic interests, and has embraced African American advancement in partisan political party offices, as candidates for elective office, and as political appointees in executive branch and judicial branch offices. This embrace of diversity was a natural development for a party rooted in urban areas that saw surges of immigration and internal migration turning their communities into highly diverse ones united by a desire to participate in urban prosperity.

Conservative policies threatening the very existence of ethnic and racial minorities were more salient than the more general conservative leaning of these populations in the U.S., even though both poor, rural whites and poor urban non-whites faced similar economic challenges (and continue to face those challenges).

*Membership In The Democratic Party Coalition Changed African Americans And Other Minorities Ideologically*

This coalition, in turn, has mobilized elites in the African American community to back a Democratic party political agenda, and to advocate for and cause the realization of African American community values in the United States, such as efforts to find common cause with Hispanic immigrants, rather than seeing them as threats, and seeing environmental protection as something that personally advances their health rather than as a threat to their jobs, that would not have been natural responses in a vacuum outside the Democratic Party coalition.

Similarly, the larger Democratic Party coalition has influenced African Americans in responding to criminal violence in their communities with calls for gun control, rather than easier access to gun ownership (e.g. through restoration of the civil rights of those with criminal convictions).

Put another way, African Americans have largely repudiated the culture of the American South within which their own ethnic subculture arose, and realigned their own subculture with that of the economically successful parts of the rest of the United States. Following that switch of cultural allegiances, their own conditions of personal safety and economic security have been relegated to second order within community differences in values that also shift the entire community's values modestly in their direction, rather than reinforcing the similar although less intense values of working class white Southerners in a similar conservative direction.

*Public Policy Also Changed African American Values*

Public policy itself has changed African American political values.

Before formal policies at the governmental level made this so, quasi-governmental political machines provide mutual support and with that economic security to new immigrants outside the structure of formal government when the concept of a welfare state was not a mature policy concept, putting the beneficiaries of this support at ease with providing political support to this movement.

In the Great Depression, the massive Democratic party led expansion of the social safety net under FDR muted the far right movements like Fascism that grew more powerful in place that did not adopt them by making people more economically secure.

On the issue of health care, there was been a sustained period of time from the adoption of the Medicaid program, until the implementation of Obamacare, where as a matter of policy driven by the political coalitions backing these programs, those in poverty (who were more often urban minorities) had more secure access to medical care, than working class individuals with no health insurance (who were more often rural whites), a substantial share of all working class people.

Affirmative action arguably made it easier for an African Americans who are ready to go to college to obtain a higher education than an academically comparable working class white person for a sustained period of time, again building loyalty to liberal ideals by providing greater economic prospects for those won over to them.

There have been time periods in many places where African Americans have more heavily utilized the social welfare safety net available than comparable poor whites, in part due to better community knowledge of how the programs work, and in part due to a lower degree of distrust of those programs.

These policies and others like them make it possible to conclude that public policy has done more to alleviate insecurity for blacks than for whites for a sustained period of time, muting somewhat differences in absolute physical and economic well being, although this argument alone is not enough to explain the reality in the absence of the rejection of ethnic and religious minorities by the more conservative party in the U.S. two party system.

**The Economic Divide Between Urban and Rural Areas In The U.S. Has Grown Wider Over The Last Couple of Generations**

In the U.S., it has also been observed that deeper partisan political divisions between urban and rural areas have tracked a widening prosperity divide between urban and rural areas. For example, [this account at Politico](https://www.politico.com/news/magazine/2020/12/01/democrats-rural-vote-wisconsin-441458) notes that:

> [T]he economic divide between rural and urban America has widened.
> Small-business growth has slowed in rural communities since the Great
> Recession, and it has only worsened with Covid-19. . . .  The source
> of our wealth is in the things we grow. But today, those things get
> shipped off into a vast global supply chain, where profits are
> siphoned off and little remains for us to save or invest. Farmers’
> share of every retail food dollar has fallen from about 50 percent in
> 1952 to 15 percent today.

**Prosperity Also Drives The Importance Of Religion And The Importance Of Religion Influences Partisan Leanings**

It is hard to disentangle the relevant factors, however, because they aren't independent from each other.

For example, the extent to which people are religious also influences their partisan leanings. All other things being equal, more religious people are more conservative and more secular people are more liberal. But, as noted above, the importance of religion in the lives of people is strongly related to economic prosperity, something that has been shown both in an international context:

[image]

The deviations from the overall average curve tend to have historical roots because values and partisan ideas change gradually on the scale of generations, not just election to election.

The countries below the curve tend to be either currently, or recently Communist countries, where atheism was a matter of official policy, or Asian countries where Islam is rare in most of the country and the role of religion in politics in these countries is different than in the West.

Countries where there was once an established religion also tend to be more secular.

Countries with a significant Muslim population and countries with religious diversity, in contrast, tend to be above the curve.

Similar strong general trends that are nonetheless not perfect are also true domestically, as one can see from [the data below](https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2016/02/29/how-religious-is-your-state/?state=alabama):

*% of adults who say religion is very important in their lives*

1. Alabama  77%
2. Mississippi  74%
3. Tennessee    71%
4. Louisiana    71%
5. Arkansas 70%
6. South Carolina   69%
7. West Virginia    64%
8. Georgia  64%
9. Oklahoma 64%
10. Texas   63%
11. Kentucky    63%
12. North Carolina  62%
13. Virginia    60%
14. New Mexico  59%
15. Utah    58%
16. South Dakota    57%
17. Missouri    56%
18. Ohio    56%
19. Nebraska    54%
20. Iowa    53%
21. Florida 53%
22. Indiana 53%
23. North Dakota    53%
24. Arizona 51%
25. Pennsylvania    51%
26. Idaho   51%
27. Kansas  50%
28. New Jersey  50%
29. Maryland    50%
30. District of Columbia    50%
31. Michigan    50%
32. Illinois    50%
33. Wyoming 49%
34. Rhode Island    48%
35. California  47%
36. Colorado    47%
37. Delaware    46%
38. Minnesota   46%
39. Oregon  45%
40. New York    45%
41. Nevada  44%
42. Montana 44%
43. Hawaii  44%
44. Washington  44%
45. Wisconsin   44%
46. Connecticut 42%
47. Alaska  41%
48. Maine   34%
49. Massachusetts   33%
50. New Hampshire   33%
51. Vermont 32%

[with per capita GDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_and_territories_by_GDP_per_capita):

U.S. states and territories by GDP per capita (current dollars)

National rank   State or territory  2018

51       Mississippi    37,948

50       Arkansas   42,454

49       West Virginia  43,053

48       Idaho  43,430

47       Alabama    45,219

46       South Carolina 45,280

45       Montana    46,609

44       Kentucky   46,898

43       New Mexico 46,954

42       Maine  47,969

41       Arizona    48,055

40       Florida    48,318

39       Oklahoma   50,613

38       Missouri   51,699

37       Michigan   53,209

36       Vermont    53,523

35       Louisiana  53,589

34       Tennessee  53,933

33       North Carolina 54,441

32       Indiana    55,172

31       Nevada 55,269

30       Utah   55,550

29       Georgia    55,832

28       Kansas 56,334

27       Oregon 56,956

26       Ohio   57,492

25       Wisconsin  57,720

24       Rhode Island   57,852

23       South Dakota   58,624

22       Iowa   59,977

21       Texas  61,167

20       Pennsylvania   61,594

—        United States  62,390

19       Virginia   62,563

18       New Hampshire  63,067

17       Colorado   63,882

16       Nebraska   63,942

15       Hawaii 64,096

14       Minnesota  64,675

13       Illinois   67,268

12       Maryland   68,573

11       New Jersey 69,378

10       Wyoming    69,900

9        North Dakota   72,597

8        Alaska 73,205

7        Washington 74,182

6        California 74,205

5        Connecticut    76,342

4        Delaware   77,253

3        Massachusetts  82,480

2        New York   85,746

1        District of Columbia   200,277

Comment: I wonder how that GDP/religion graph looks if you use median GDP instead of average. Perhaps the US has a surprisingly high number of very rich people?

Comment: @user253751 It wouldn't change much. The US would still have a comparable wealth per capita to countries like Japan, Australia or Western Europe, all of which are considerably less religious.

Comment: (actually "median GDP per capita" doesn't make sense, but "median wage" does)

Comment: The problem here is that you are trying to make sense of things on a one-dimensional scale, when US politics (and probably politics anywhere) just doesn't work like that.  Just for one instance of many, under conservative/Republican, you have the religious right social conservatives (who want government to make everyone live according to their beliefs), and the libertarian "keep the damned government out of my life" ones, who are united only by their shared detestation of liberals.

Comment: @jamesqf There is pretty solid empirical evidence to show that U.S. politics, while not perfectly matched to a one-dimensional scale is very well approximated by one at both the elected official level and in the rank and file. This is beyond the scope of a single short comment, however. For elected officials see:  https://www.swarthmore.edu/SocSci/rvalell1/documents/Nominate_000.pdf

Comment: If you are going to claim liberals are favored by people with higher GDP you should likely at least touch on the fact the minorities that tend to struggle socioeconomically tend to also heavily lean democratic, as it seems an obvious counter point to your claim.

Comment: @dsollen The question is about the geographical lean of geographic regions. People don't have GDP, regions do. At the geographic level unit of analysis, the GDP approach is pretty effective. If you want to slice and dice the political world more finely you'll need more elaborate models.

Comment: @ohwilleke Yes people don't have GDP, but GDP basically boils down to "these people make more on average", GDP is just a way of measuring that.  So the argument that high GDP regions are prone to democratic values seems to translate to "people that are prone to making more are prone to liberalism" of which the obvious question is "why does this subgroup that is prone to not making allot also heavily biased towards liberalism".   I don't think your arguments are wrong, I just think elaborating specifically on the later would enhance the question.

Comment: @dsollen I've analyzed the issue in the past (although not a Politics.SE) See, e.g. https://washparkprophet.blogspot.com/2015/01/african-american-political-identity-in.html but I'd double the length of the answer and not advance the question asked very much by doing so. Maybe another day.. Feel free to borrow ideas from there if you want to provide your own answer.

Comment: Rank and file one v. two dimensionality analyzed by CATO with a libertarian bent acknowledges that there are more voters along the main dimension than orthogonal to it, but also illustrates that the it is difficult to quantify since definitional issues are largely arbitrary. https://www.cato.org/blog/how-many-libertarians-are-there-answer-depends-method

Comment: @ohwilleke Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I guess the main follow up question (which you already partially answered, just not fully) is the exact mechanism: why is urbanization and income so highly correlated with political affiliation?

Answer (score 4):

There is the big issue of correlation versus causation.

Things like higher education, higher population density and less important role of religion all have positive correlation with leaning democrat. This is scientifically rigorous. You can quantify this things (maybe not religion but the others) and then simply compute the correlation.

Causal relationships on the other hand are almost impossible to establish. On something as complicated as politics humans just aren't monocausal.

Comment: I agree. At a minimum, though, people should have ran a regression with these competing variables and see which ones have higher marginal explanatory power?

Comment: @JLi Sure but then all the details start to matter. Do you measure at state or county level? Which variables do you include in your analysis? How do you put education into a numerical variable? Is leaning democrat the result of the last election, previous ones or some polling result using self identification?

Comment: I would be happy to learn about results at all levels. If you know any I would love to learn.